# Image in recent post of Wordpress Q and A theme

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using Instant-QA theme, need to update the recent Post `widget` with image of the user who has asked the questions. I am using the below code in `functions.php` of subdomain of `wordpress` website. Currently its showing the simple post--- Any guess in below code-- ?

```
function print_requested_template_part() {
    // Respond only to requests from the same address... 
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['including_template_part']) && isset($_GET['load_part']) && $_GET['load_part'] != '' ) {
        $part = $_GET['load_part'];
        $func = 'render_' . str_replace('-', '_', $part); // if you have declared a function called "render_footer_include", then "?load_part=footer_include"
        if ( function_exists($func) ) {
            // Allow for passing parameters to the function
            if ( isset($_GET['params']) ) {
                $params = $_GET['params'];
                $params = ( strpos($params, ',') !== false )? explode(',', $params) : array($params);
                call_user_func_array($func, $params);
            } else {
                call_user_func($func);
            }
        }
        exit; // if we don't exit here, a whole page will be printed => bad! it's better to have empty footer than a footer with the whole main site...
    }
}
add_action('init', 'print_requested_template_part', 1);

function render_my_recent_posts( $numberposts = 5 ) { ?>

    <ul>
    <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        }
    ?>
    </ul><?php
}
```

Comment: If you are asking for us to review your code you should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. If you're asking a question it needs to be more obvious what the question is

Comment: Me wants to display the image in recent post like [link]http://questions.admissiontimes.com. On RIght Hand Side, its simply display the recent post, i need to show them with the Avatar image. Sounds nice and more clearly this time ?

Comment: Like Green and Black in given link

Comment: you can use this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

Answer (score 0):

DO not waste you time to indulge urself in the above code. Usel below plugin and gets the immediate output.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recent-comments-with-avatars/ Use this plugin

Thankyou